# How to refactor Symfony 5 controller to comply with SOLID design principles

Tags: design-patterns, symfony4

I am trying to create this API endpoint that will accept JSON payload and will calculate quote based on provided factors and their ratings.

I have Entities that contain information about:

- `age`
- `postcode`
- `ABI code`
  ratings.

These `AgeRating`, `PostcodeRating` and `AbiRating` entities implement `RatingFactorInterface` to force implementation of `getRatingFactor()` method.

`QuoteController` seems to be violating *Single Responsibility* and *Open/Close* design principles as the factors like `age`, `postcode` can change - extra factor can be added or one of the factors might not be used.

I was thinking maybe it would be possible for rating factors to be specified in the dependency injection container, but can't seem find a good example how this would work especially with factors that depend on other services like `AbiCodeRating` which also depends on ABI code which is returned by using third party API which accepts car registration number.

#### Question

How do I refactor the controller and services so I'm not violating Single Responsibility and Open / Close design principles?

#### POST JSON Payload example

```
{
    "age": 20,
    "postcode": "PE3 8AF",
    "regNo": "PJ63 LXR"
}
```

#### QuoteController

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Repository\AbiCodeRatingRepository;
use App\Repository\AgeRatingRepository;
use App\Repository\PostcodeRatingRepository;
use App\Service\AbiCodeLookup;
use App\Service\QuoteCalculator;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * Class QuoteController
 * @package App\Controller
 */
class QuoteController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="quote")
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param AbiCodeRatingRepository $abiCodeRatingRepository
     * @param AgeRatingRepository $ageRatingRepository
     * @param PostcodeRatingRepository $postcodeRatingRepository
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function index(Request $request, AbiCodeRatingRepository $abiCodeRatingRepository, AgeRatingRepository $ageRatingRepository, PostcodeRatingRepository $postcodeRatingRepository)
    {
        try{

            $request = $this->transformJsonBody($request);

            /**
             * Quoting engine could be used with a different set of rating factors!
             * Meaning age, postcode and regNo maybe not be required, some other rating factors might be introduced
             * How to make controller to accept rating factors dynamically?
             */
            if (!$request || !$request->get('age') || !$request->request->get('postcode') || !$request->get('regNo')){
                throw new \Exception();
            }

            /**
             * call to a third party API to look up the vehicle registration number and return an ABI code
             * this is only required if AbiRating is used with the quoting engine
             */
            $abiCode          = AbiCodeLookup::getAbiCode($request->get('regNo'));
            /**
             * $abiCode is only required if postcodeRating is used by quoting engine
             */
            $ratingFactors[]  = $abiCodeRatingRepository->findOneBy(["abiCode"=>$abiCode]);
            $ratingFactors[]  = $ageRatingRepository->findOneBy(["age"=>$request->get("age")]);
            /**
             * $area is only required if postcodeRating is used by quoting engine
             */
            $area             = substr($request->get("postcode"),0,3);
            $ratingFactors[]  = $postcodeRatingRepository->findByPostcodeArea($area);
            $premiumTotal     = QuoteCalculator::calculate($ratingFactors);

            $data = [
                'status' => 200,
                'success' => "Quote created successfully",
                'quote' => $premiumTotal
            ];

            return new JsonResponse($data,200);

        }catch (\Exception $e){
            $data = [
                'status' => 422,
                'errors' => "Data is not valid",
            ];
            return new JsonResponse($data,422);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Request
     */
    protected function transformJsonBody(Request $request)
    {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        if ($data === null) {
            return $request;
        }

        $request->request->replace($data);

        return $request;
    }
}
```

#### AbiCodeRating

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\AbiCodeRatingRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AbiCodeRatingRepository::class)
 */
class AbiCodeRating implements RatingFactorInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $abiCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $ratingFactor;

    public function getAbiCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->abiCode;
    }

    public function setAbiCode(string $abiCode): self
    {
        $this->abiCode = $abiCode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRatingFactor(): ?float
    {
        return $this->ratingFactor;
    }

    public function setRatingFactor(?float $ratingFactor): self
    {
        $this->ratingFactor = $ratingFactor;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

#### AgeRating

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\AgeRatingRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AgeRatingRepository::class)
 */
class AgeRating implements RatingFactorInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $age;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $ratingFactor;

    public function getAge(): ?int
    {
        return $this->age;
    }

    public function setAge(int $age): self
    {
        $this->age = $age;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRatingFactor(): ?float
    {
        return $this->ratingFactor;
    }

    public function setRatingFactor(?float $ratingFactor): self
    {
        $this->ratingFactor = $ratingFactor;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

#### PostcodeRating

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\PostcodeRatingRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=PostcodeRatingRepository::class)
 */
class PostcodeRating implements RatingFactorInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=4)
     */
    private $postcodeArea;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $ratingFactor;

    public function getPostcodeArea(): ?string
    {
        return $this->postcodeArea;
    }

    public function setPostcodeArea(string $postcodeArea): self
    {
        $this->postcodeArea = $postcodeArea;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRatingFactor(): ?float
    {
        return $this->ratingFactor;
    }

    public function setRatingFactor(?float $ratingFactor): self
    {
        $this->ratingFactor = $ratingFactor;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

#### RatingFactorInterface

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

interface RatingFactorInterface
{
    /**
     * @return float|null
     */
    public function getRatingFactor(): ?float;
}
```

#### AbiCodeRatingRepository

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\AbiCodeRating;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @method AbiCodeRating|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method AbiCodeRating|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method AbiCodeRating[]    findAll()
 * @method AbiCodeRating[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class AbiCodeRatingRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, AbiCodeRating::class);
    }
}
```

#### AgeRatingRepository

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\AgeRating;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @method AgeRating|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method AgeRating|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method AgeRating[]    findAll()
 * @method AgeRating[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class AgeRatingRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, AgeRating::class);
    }
}
```

#### PostcodeRatingRepository

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\PostcodeRating;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @method PostcodeRating|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method PostcodeRating|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method PostcodeRating[]    findAll()
 * @method PostcodeRating[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class PostcodeRatingRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, PostcodeRating::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return PostcodeRating Returns PostcodeRating objects based on area
     */

    public function findByPostcodeArea($area): ?PostcodeRating
    {
        return $this->findOneBy(["postcodeArea"=>$area]);
    }
}
```

#### AbiCodeLookup

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

class AbiCodeLookup
{
    public static function getAbiCode(string $regNumber){

        /**
         * create a request to third party api which would return abi code
         * How to configure this service to be used only with regNo factor
         */
        return "22529902";
    }
}
```

#### QuoteCalculator

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use App\Entity\RatingFactorInterface;
    
/**
 * Class QuoteCalculator
 */
class QuoteCalculator
{
    /**
     * @param array $ratingFactors
     * @return float
     */
    public static function calculate(array $ratingFactors): float
    {
        $premiumTotal = 500;
        foreach ($ratingFactors as $ratingFactor){
            $premiumTotal = $premiumTotal * ($ratingFactor instanceof RatingFactorInterface ? $ratingFactor->getRatingFactor() : 1);
        }
        return $premiumTotal ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First I think that is important to redefine the **SRP** principle for better understanding. Robert C. Martin defines responsibility as **a reason to change**, so a class should've *just one* reason to change.

In my humble opinion a *controller* should only care about receiving the request then hand that input over to the service or services that handle the logic and create a response. That would be **its reason to change**.

In your code, the controller coordinates the logic. It knows which repositories to call, which criteria to apply, which services to execute, the order to do it... So, at least, it has a *second* reason for changing.

What should it do then? Well, the controller should handle the request, then transform it to some kind of data structure (like a dummy object, ie: DTO) using a transformer, or similar. When you have that, you handle that data to a service that *knows* the flow of the use case you want to execute (this service is the one with all the dependencies like repositories, or the calculator service.. or even more complex services with their own dependencies).

I don't like the static calls either, most of the time they just *hide* dependencies and violate **DI**, being just structured code in a class oriented disguise.

When you look at your controller it's not clear which dependencies it has, even if you were to move your code to the service layer, with all those static calls the dependencies would still be hidden and you would've to look at everyline to see which services it's using.

```
<?php

class QuoteUseCase {
  
  public function __construct($AbiCodeLookup, $abiCodeRatingRepository, ageRatingRepository...){
  
  }
  
  public function handle(RatingFactor $ratingFactors){
    //here would be your logic
  }
}
```

If you look at this pseudocode, you can easily see which dependencies it has (codeLookUp, codeRatingRepo, ageRatingRepo...) and you can see as well which are the arguments it need to perform the *use case* (ratingFactors). This RatingFactor would perform the role of the dummy object I was talking about earlier.

You may be wondering, why would you need to do all this, in the end I just moved some code from one class to another. Well, think about the following scenario:

Imagine tomorrow you have to perform the exact same use case but from the command line instead of a request. What would you do? Would you duplicate all your code?

If you have that extra service layer that contains the use case logic you could just make a call from a Symfony Command, a PHP Script or whatever and that would be it: you create the same dummy object from command line parameters this time, you get the service with all its dependencies, you hand the DTO to the handle method and that's it.

PS: It's all about trade-offs, maybe in your example there's no real need to do that kind of separation. It's just **as bad** to refactor and to apply, the so called, principles (that end adding complexity) than to never apply them at all.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, so if i lets say have one service dependency in the QuoteController -> public function index(Request $request, QuoteCalculator $quoteCalculator) - QuoteCalculator also depends on array of objects that implement getRatingFactor() - is there a way to create $ratingFactors array based on configuration in config/services.yaml something like below:

Comment: `code` parameters:
    rating_factors:
        - App\Service\AbiCodeRatingUseCase
        - App\Service\AgeRatingUseCase
        - App\Service\PostcodeRatingUseCase
services: 
    app.quote_calculator:
        class: App\Service\QuoteCalculator
        arguments:
            $ratingFactors: "%rating_factors%" `code`

Comment: is there a way in service configuration to set "array" argument like $ratingFactors[] in my case which would define which use cases are required in a particular scenario? i don't seem to find on symfony docs about array arguments as dependency although there seems to be array parameters https://symfony.com/doc/2.1/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html#array-parameters

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. RatingFactors come from the Request, don't they? You can use a Transformer class, some ParamConverters, or something similar to handle the request and get the object. QuoteCalculator is, on the other hand, configured at "compilation" time (when Symfony builds the cache and wires everything). With the "RatingFactors" class I was just making an example, it would be the DTO that has the values that came in the JSON (maybe with an initial validation of types, and stuff like that).